# Pandas: Show total only once per group

Tags: python, pandas

**I have this data:**

```py
Description Card Member Cost
"apple" "adam" 2
"apple" "adam" 2
"pear" "bob" 7 
"orange" "alice" 8
"orange" "alice" 8
"orange" "alice" 8
```

**I am trying to add a total column that looks like this:**

```py
Description Card Member Cost **total**
"apple" "adam" 2 
"apple" "adam" 2 4
"pear" "bob" 7 7
"orange" "alice" 8 
"orange" "alice" 8
"orange" "alice" 8 24
```

I have tried to use `df["Total"] = df.groupby('Card Member')['Cost'].transform('sum')`

Although it generates totals after every single row whereas I just want the total to be displayed once at the end of each members per row.

This is what it generates:

```py
Description Card Member Cost **total**
"apple" "adam" 2 4
"apple" "adam" 2 4
"pear" "bob" 7 7
"orange" "alice" 8 24 
"orange" "alice" 8 24
"orange" "alice" 8 24
```

As you can see the totals are repeated over and over again which makes my data not as readable. I only want the total row values to display once and then end of each member rather than have them constantly appear over and over again.

I was thinking about looping and deleting the value if it is not equal to the next iteration but this will cause issues if the totals are the same for different members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the last rows with `duplicated`:

```
s = ~df.duplicated(['Description','CardMember'], keep='last')

df.loc[s,'total'] = df.groupby(['Description', 'CardMember'], sort=False)['Cost'].transform('sum')
```

Output:

```
  Description CardMember  Cost  total
0     "apple"     "adam"     2    NaN
1     "apple"     "adam"     2    4.0
2      "pear"      "bob"     7    7.0
3    "orange"    "alice"     8    NaN
4    "orange"    "alice"     8    NaN
5    "orange"    "alice"     8   24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
df["total"] = 0

for name in df["Card Member"].unique():
    df_sel = df[df["Card Memebr"] == name]
    df_sel.iloc[len(df_sel) - 1, 4] = df_sel["Cost"].sum()
    df[df["Card Member"] == name] = df_sel
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) with [`pd.Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with `keep` parameter set to `last` here.

```
s = df.groupby('Card Member')['Cost'].transform('sum')
df.assign(total = s.mask(s.duplicated(keep = 'last'))

       Desc      mem  cost  total
0   "apple"   "adam"     2    NaN
1   "apple"   "adam"     2    4.0
2    "pear"    "bob"     7    7.0
3  "orange"  "alice"     8    NaN
4  "orange"  "alice"     8    NaN
5  "orange"  "alice"     8   24.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`np.where` version:

```
df["Total"] = np.where(~df['Card Member'].duplicated('last'),
                       df.groupby('Card Member')['Cost'].transform('sum'),
                       None)
```

`df['Description'].duplicated('last')` marks the last value for each duplicated group as `False`, so `~df['Description'].duplicated('last')` can be used to mark those values as `True` and only enter your `groupby` calculation in those rows.

Answer (score 0):

Let us do it with `apply`

```
s=df.groupby(['Description','Card'],as_index=False).MemberCost.apply(lambda x : pd.Series(x.sum(),index=[x.index[-1]])).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df['New']=s
df
Out[103]: 
  Description     Card  MemberCost   New
0     "apple"   "adam"           2   NaN
1     "apple"   "adam"           2   4.0
2      "pear"    "bob"           7   7.0
3    "orange"  "alice"           8   NaN
4    "orange"  "alice"           8   NaN
5    "orange"  "alice"           8  24.0
```